# How do I get shapely polygon intersection area?

Tags: python, shapely

In an example case, at debug point, y=40000, x=1500, z=0. Small polygon is totally inside big and I thought z should be 1500. `contains` doesn't find the case at all.

```
for big_polygon in big_polygons:
    for small_polygon in small_polygons:
        if big_polygon.intersects(small_polygon):
            y=big_polygon.area
            x=small_polygon.area
            z=big_polygon.intersection(small_polygon).area
            #debug point
```

Comment: What are small_polygon and big_polygon geometries? Your code works as expected.

Comment: @menes if smaller polygon intersects bigger, why is intersection area zero?